# Why is this function not printing all the values?

Tags: java

I am totally new to Java, I am wondering why this function is not printing anything.

```
public class testingStuff {
    public  String func(){
        int i;
        String foo = "";
        for (i=0; i<3; i++ ){
            foo = "The number is "+i + " \n";
        }

        return foo;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        testingStuff stuff = new testingStuff();
        stuff.func();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't tell it to print anything. Where is a statement that performs output?

Comment: Well basically what I wanted to do is to assign the value of what should be printed to that `foo` variable and return it!

Comment: You keep overwriting the variable `foo` inside your for loop. You should instead append a `StringBuffer` or at least use `+=` to return the full string from the loop.

Comment: "I wrote a program that doesn't print anything. Why doesn't it print anything?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class testingStuff 
{
    public String func()
    {
       int i;
       String foo = "";
       for (i=0; i<3; i++ ) 
       {
          foo += "The number is "+i + " \n";
       }

      return foo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
       testingStuff stuff = new testingStuff();
       String s = stuff.func();
       System.out.println(s); //this will print to console.
    }
}
```

or if you prefer this instead:

```
public void func()
{
   int i;
   String foo = "";
   for (i=0; i<3; i++ ) 
   {
      foo = "The number is " + i;
      System.out.println(foo);
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   testingStuff stuff = new testingStuff();
   stuff.func();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not use `System.out.println()` for example to print the values.
All you do is assign a sentence to the local variable `foo` then return with its last value (without using it).

Try:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++ ){
    System.out.println("The number is "+i + " \n");
}
```

Comment: So how can I actually return what is printer in a the return statement of the function?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to create the strings then return its `toString()`.

Comment: `StringBuilder`'s `toString`method produces a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Little modification in code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testingStuff stuff = new testingStuff();
        System.out.println(stuff.func()); // prints the result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestingStuff {
public void func(){        
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++ ){
        System.out.println("The number is " + i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)  
{
    new testingStuff().func();
}
```

}

1. Try to follow naming convention. First letter of class should be capital.
2. index inside for loop can be declared inline.
3. System.out.println prints new line char implicitly, no need to print it explicitly
4. An object can be instantiated without storing its reference (anonymous object)